# how to change url format and HIDE php files in it

Tags: php, html

We're trying to setup a local website .. and it's php based.

So, my question is :

For example, when I click "login", I see the URL like this: "http://sitename.com/login.php".

Or, when it's logged in, it looks like this: "sitename.com/siginin.php?do=acctmain"

We want to change the URL format and hide all php files..

We want to make the URL format look like this, for example:

sitename.com/login/ (or, when it's logged in: "sitename.com/myaccount/main/")

No php file to be shown, that's what we want.

Who can help, please?

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for url rewriting using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and `RewriteRule`s.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache, look into [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).